# Comments are not showing up

Tags: python, django

Today I am trying to make comments section, where users can post comments. This is my code:

```
#views.py

def add_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save()
            save_it.save()
            comments = Comment.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'task-result.html', {
        'form': form, 'comment': comments,
        })
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'Task-form.html', {
        'form': form,
        })
#HTML
<body>
    <h3>Comments</h3>
    {% for a in comments %}
    <li>{{ a.body }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% csrf_token %}
</body>
```

However, nothing is printed out. What is wrong?

Comment: `save_it.save()` is not needed - it saves an object that is already saved in the line just before that.

Comment: `{% csrf_token %}` makes no sense if it is outside of a `<form>`HTML element.

Comment: Where are you passing the comments if it is not a POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one of the following:

1. Change your template to

   {% for a in comment %}
2. Change your view to return `comments` instead of `comment`

   return render(request, 'task-result.html', {
           'form': form, 'comments': comments,
           })